# PHP :1D array to 2D array

Tags: php, arrays, loops

Hi I have a 1D array (1 by 20) that I would like to transform to a 2D Array (4 by 5)

```
$winning_number  = 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20
```

to

```
1 2 3 4 5
6 7 8 9 10
11 12 13 14 15
16 17 18 19 20
```

right now I am using this code:

```
foreach ($wining_no as $boulex)
{

    for($i=0;$i<$5;$i++)
    {
        if($i==0)
        {
            for($j=0;$j<$4;$j++)
            {   
                $boule_array[$j][$i] = $boulex;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

For some reason this does not work

Comment: [`array_chunk($winning_no, 5);`](http://php.net/array_chunk)

Comment: Maybe the problem is the typo: `$4;` inside of the third loop, in the condition. `$j=0;$j<$4;$j++`. Because I think you mean the integer `4`.

Comment: Same as on line 4 $5 -> 5

Answer (score 2):

You could use the [`array_chunk($array, $size)`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-chunk.php) function
For you it would be like this

```
array_chunk($winning_number, 5);
```